# Py2Exe error: error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: run-py3.5-win32.exe'

Tags: python, windows, exe, py2exe

Similar Questions have been asked to this before, however I have tried quite a lot and nothing seems to be working my exact error is:

```
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Byron\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\lib\\site-packages\\py2exe\\run-py3.5-win32.exe'
```

What I have tried:

- Reinstalling Py2Exe (a few times via Pip & Installer)
- Disabling Anti-Virus

Anything else:

- I initially installed using Pip after reinstalling python to a different directory
- I reinstalled using a MS Windows Installer
- I'm using Python 3.5
- I have checked where Py2Exe is checking for this file and it is not present or visible.
- I have included a screenshot of my Py2Exe installation.

**Py2Exe Installation Image**

[image: Py2Exe install Image]

Comment: Why is it Byron Filer in screenshot and just Byron in error you are getting?

Comment: [Here is the answer I believe you are looking for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400576/py2exe-error-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1):

Py2exe does not support python 3.5 so the file doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Yes, currently only exists C:\Users\i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\py2exe\run_w-py3.4-win32.exe